# Nonlinear Gauss-Seidel for solving a PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization, numerical-calculus

I am not getting anywhere with this task:

> Consider the following PDE:
> $$-\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}(x)+cu(x)\frac{du}{dx}(x) = f(x),\,\, 0 < x < 1,\,\, u(0)=0,\,\, u(1)=1$$
> Divide the interval $[0,1]$ into $n$ subintervals of width $h=1/n$.
> Use central difference approximation
> $$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2}(x_i) \approx \frac{u_{i+1}-2u_i +u_{i-1}}{h^2}$$
> and
> $$\frac{du}{dx}(x_i) \approx \frac{u_{i+1}-u_{i-1}}{2h}$$
> to find a nonlinear system for $u_2,...,u_n$.
>
> Then state the nonlinear Gauss-Seidel for the obtained system.

Maybe you could lead me through the task or give some hints what to do. I don't know what Finite Differences have got to do with finding a nonlinear system, and I only know linear Gauss-Seidel so far. Google research wasn't helpful to me. I would be so grateful for at least a rough solution to this problem.

Comment: First write the equation system on the form $F(u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_i,\ldots,u_n) = 0$. Then solve the equation for $u_i$, i.e. $u_i = G(u_0,u_1,\ldots,u_{i-1},u_{i+1},\ldots,u_n)$ to get your iteration scheme. In general, when we cannot do it analytically, we ca use the iteration (Newton-Gauss-Seidel) scheme from $u_i \leftarrow u_i - F / (dF/du_i)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are being asked to present a modification of the fixed point method that uses the latest values of the already computed components. For instance, lets say that the nonlinear equation
$$
-\frac{1}{h^2}(u_{i+1}-2u_i+u_{i-1})+ \frac{c}{2h} u_i (u_{i+1}-u_{i-1}) = f_i
$$

is recasted as

$$
u_i = \dfrac{2h^2 f_i+2(u_{i+1} + u_{i-1})}{4+c h (u_{i+1}-u_{i-1})}.
$$

The usual fixed point would read
$$
u_i^{(k+1)} = \dfrac{2h^2 f_i+2\left(u_{i+1}^{(k)} + u_{i-1}^{(k)}\right)}{4+c h \left(u_{i+1}^{(k)}-u_{i-1}^{(k)}\right)}
$$

However, assuming that when you are computing $u_i^{(k+1)}$ you have already computed $u_{i-1}^{(k+1)}$, you can consider the iteration

$$
u_i^{(k+1)} = \dfrac{2h^2 f_i+2\left(u_{i+1}^{(k)} + \color{red}{u_{i-1}^{(k+1)}}\right)}{4+c h \left(u_{i+1}^{(k)}-\color{red}{u_{i-1}^{(k+1)}}\right)}.
$$